# Kusto Query: Get the latest date in a column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto table, one of the column(ReceivedDate) is holding datetime. How to find the latest date, in this case it is 2021-07-27 00:00:00.0000000. I want to collect this value into a variable to use it in where clause.

```
ReceivedDate
2021-07-21 00:00:00.0000000
2021-07-22 00:00:00.0000000
2021-07-23 00:00:00.0000000
2021-07-24 00:00:00.0000000
2021-07-25 00:00:00.0000000
2021-07-26 00:00:00.0000000
2021-07-27 00:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
let dt = toscalar(TableName | summarize max(ReceivedDate));
OtherTableName
| where Timestamp > dt
| ...
```